# Authenticate an EWS application - what's the next step

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS in a Windows Service to access different users calenders. Since office 365 basic authentication is deprecated I need to add support for OAuth. I followed the steps in this link [Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth) and it works fine. However, my application is used by many customers and what I don't understand is what my customers are supposed to do. Do they also have to add my application in their 365 account? I was under the impression that a customer could find my app in a global directory or something, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: If you made your Application registration Multi-Tennant then each tenant that is to use you application will need to consent to its use in their Tenant . The Directory your talking about it probably https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us but your app needs to be certified etc

Comment: Okay, so they have to register the application the same way I had to do?

Comment: No if you made your registration multi tennant then they can consent to your registration in their tenant

Comment: Should it show in "Enterprise applications | Admin consent requests (Preview)" in tenant I'm trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes once consented to in the tennant it will appear there

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-consent-for-an-entire-tenant) that described everything in detail.